# From where the inline style in list page product-info coming from?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I want to give a `height` to `product-info` div in category page. when I inspect the element, already height property is defined `inline`. But when I inspect the code in `list.phtml` there is no inline style defined for `product-info`. I just dont know where those inline styles are coming from.

Someone explain me this please.

Comment: may be appended by some jQuery scripts

Comment: Hey yea..   It is in `app.js` in line no:1097. Thank you. I have upvoted your comment.